# Verifying installation: 'apt-cache policy' vs 'which'

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, git

I have searched for every variation of this question for days and I have not been able to find a clear explanation therefore I come to the collective knowledge here in the hopes of resolving my installation questions on a Linux distro.

I have installed(or at least attempted to) a couple of packages from github and I think I may have installed them properly because when I use `which <package>` or `<package> -h` I can see the path (all are in /usr/bin/) and the commands associated with the correct programs, however, when I use `apt-cache` the packages cannot be found.

My question is this: what exactly is the difference in `apt-cache policy`, `which`, and using `-h` when checking the installation of packages? I installed each package slightly differently and neither of them I installed using the software center for Ubuntu.

For one package:

```
git clone "package.git"
make
sudo ln -s ~/path/to/package_clone /usr/local/bin/.
```

for another:

```
git clone https://github.com/package.git
cd pkg.dir/
sudo python setup.py install
pkg.dir -h
```

Comment: By the way, `type <program>` is also useful for this sort of thing, and will show functions, aliases, and bash builtins as well.

Answer (score 0):

`apt-cache` is an information tool of the package manager `apt`/`dpkg`. It only has information about packages you installed through them (note that the Software Center is just a GUI front-end for them) i.e. regular .deb packages (including everything from the official repositories and PPAs).

If you install applications manually by either just copying their folders or running installation scripts or `make` commands, those are not regular packages and therefore not managed by the package manager. That's why `apt-cache` can not find any information about the packages - they simply are no packages at all.

---

The `which` command on the other hand is not related to packages, it simply shows you which executable would get run if you type a specific command by searching all directories specified in the `$PATH` environment variable for executable files of a matching name.

Answer (score 0):

- By running `apt-cache policy <package`. You display an information about the priority selection of the named package.

  The package in question must be installed by `apt-get` beforehand. It will not be aware of the packages you installed manually (for example with `git` command).
- By running `which` command you ask your system what would be the exact path of a program if you tried to execute it.

  Each user has a `PATH` environment variable defined which contains the list of the directories the OS will search (one by one) for the exact match of the program name you typed. You can display the value of `PATH` with the following command:

  ```
  echo "$PATH"
  ```

  You might get a result similar to: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/snap/bin".

  If you type:

  ```
  which mail
  ```

  The system will check:

  - does `/usr/local/sbin` contain `mail`? -- No.
  - does `/usr/local/bin` contain `mail`? -- No.
  - does `/usr/local/bin` contain `mail`? -- No.
  - does `/usr/bin` contain `mail`? -- Yes. So print `/usr/bin`.

  It means if you tried to run:

  ```
  mail
  ```

  The system will run the `/usr/bin/mail` program.

  The most common use of `which` command is to ensure you are running the correct version of a program in case you have several versions installed. Or verifying whether a program can be run at all.
- By running a program with `-h` argument you in fact try to execute it. Depending on the exact implementation it might display help, for example:

  ```
  mail -h
  ```

  However, remember that `-h` is a customary argument, it is up to the program itself to respond. Not all programs display help with this argument, some might return an error, some might ignore and run, some might use it for a very different purpose.

---

There is no "official" way of verifying if a manually installed program is installed properly, but the two latter commands (`which` and trying to execute a program directly) will give you the best approximation.

Instead of help you might try running a program with `--version` (or `-v`) argument which is a customary way to ask an executed program to display its version.